# "That it happened"

Tags: meaning

It was as Harry dodged another Bludger which went spinning dangerously past his head **that it happened**. His broom gave a sudden, frightening lurch. For a split second, he thought he was going to fall. He gripped the broom tightly with both his hands and knees. He’d never felt anything like that.

Is "that it happened " here a relative clause? If not, what is it? What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [cleft sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence).

Logically it is the exactly same as

> It happened as Harry dodged another Bludger which went spinning dangerously past his head.

but the verb is delayed for rhetorical effect.